# I have a simple form with a submit button. How do I make the submit button AND the enter key submit the form?

Tags: javascript, html

I am using a variation of the following code. When I press the enter key it refreshes the entire web page, rather than submitting the form. I tried searching but I know absolutely nothing about coding so none of the other answers helped me as they were not specific to my code. Thanks in advance, I really appreciate the help!

```
<html>
<head>
<head>
<style>
.button {
background-color: blue; /* Green */
border: 1;
color: white;
padding: 8px 10px;
text-align: center;
text-decoration: none;
display: inline-block;
font-size: 16px;
margin: 4px 2px;
cursor: pointer;
}
input {
width: 200px;
height: 30px;
background-color : #d1d1d1; 
border-style:groove;
}

</style>

</head>
<body>

<form name="login" method=POST>
<center>


<strong>Password:<strong>

<input  type="password" name="pswrd" onkeydown = "if (event.keyCode == 13) 
document.getElementById('pwsubmit').click()" />
<button class="button" id="pwsubmit" type="button" 
onclick="check(this.form)" value="Login"/>Submit</button></center>


</form>
<script language="javascript">

function checkentry(e)
{


document.getElementById("pswrd")
.addEventListener("keyup", function(event) {
event.preventDefault();
if (event.keyCode == 13) {
    document.getElementById("id_of_button").click();
}
});


}

function check(form)
{

//  The list below MUST contain all valid passwords

if (['laura', 'molly', 'katie', 'chris'].indexOf(form.pswrd.value) >= 0) {

// Go to different websites/weebly pages based on the entered password

switch(form.pswrd.value) {
  case "laura":
    window.open('http://www.bk.com','_self');
    break;
  case "molly":
    window.open('http://www.mcdonalds.com','_self');
    break;
  case "katie":
    window.open('https://www.supermacs.ie/','_self');
    break;
  case "chris":
    window.open('https://www.kfc.ie/','_self');
    break;
}
}

// Show following message if invalid password entered

else {alert("Invalid password entered!!!")}
}
</script>
</body>
```

Comment: Welcome.  Please read how to create an [mcve] - with the focus on _minimal_.  As a troubleshooting strategy, it will help tremendously to reduce your code the the _minimum_ that recreates the problem, and then you'll get better help here :)

Comment: I don't understand whats the point of the question... by default if you have a `form` and add something in an input field within it, and then press Enter, it will submit. And if  you also happen to have a `<button type="submit">Submit</button>` within that form, clicking the button will also do the work.

Comment: The point is that using the above code, pressing Enter is NOT submitting the form. So I am trying to find a fix that that pressing enter does submit the form/

Answer (score 0):

The default behavior of the forms in the HTML is that the enter key will invoke the first next submit button of the form after the input element.

Here is an example:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<h2>HTML Forms</h2>

<form>
  First name:<br>
  <input type="text" name="firstname" value="Mickey">
  <br>
  Last name:<br>
  <input type="text" name="lastname" value="Mouse">
  <br><br>
  <button type="submit" onclick="sayHello()">OK</button>
</form> 

<script>
function sayHello(){
 alert('Hello every body!');
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

HTML forms have an attribute named `action`. This attribute has a default behavior also. This behavior is as follow (from https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_forms.asp):

> The action attribute defines the action to be performed when the form
>   is submitted. Normally, the form data is sent to a web page on the
>   server when the user clicks on the submit button. If the action
>   attribute is omitted, the action is set to the current page.

So when you hit enter key in the text field the form is submitted and the current page is reloaded.

To prevent this behavior you could use `peventDefault()` function which prevents this default behavior.

So a simplified edited version of your sample code could be as follow:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

    <h2>HTML Forms</h2>

    <form id="myForm" onsubmit="check(event)">
        <strong>Password:<strong>

        <input  type="password" name="pswrd" />
        <button class="button" id="pwsubmit" type="button" onclick="check(event)" value="Login">Submit</button>

    </form>

    <script>

        function check(event)
        {
            event.preventDefault();
            var form = document.getElementById('myForm');

            if (['laura', 'molly', 'katie', 'chris'].indexOf(form.pswrd.value) >= 0) {
                switch(form.pswrd.value) {
                    case "laura":
                    window.open('http://www.bk.com','_self');
                    break;
                    case "molly":
                    window.open('http://www.mcdonalds.com','_self');
                    break;
                    case "katie":
                    window.open('https://www.supermacs.ie/','_self');
                    break;
                    case "chris":
                    window.open('https://www.kfc.ie/','_self');
                    break;
                }
            } else {
                    alert("Invalid password entered!!!")
            }
        }
    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

Note that your code has some syntax error also.

Comment: Thank you, so do you know why my form is not working when I hit the enter key? Do I have something out of order?

Comment: @GrantHertzog I edit my post to answer your question. Check it.